# How do I properly save a Mongoose document?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

thanks in advance for your attention on this pretty basic question! I'm currently working on a FreeCodeCamp project involving Node, MongoDB and Mongoose ([here's my Glitch project](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/jade-precious-falcon)), and I'm very confused as to what is going on when I call `.save()` on a Mongoose model. You can see the full context on Glitch, but here is the specific part that's not behaving as I'd expect it to:

```
const { User } = require("./models/user");

...

app.post("/api/exercise/new-user", (req, res) => {
  var newUser = new User({ name: req.body.username });
  newUser.save((error) => console.error(error));
  res.json({username: newUser.name, _id: newUser._id})
});
```

Here's `models/user.js`:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

exports.User = mongoose.model(
  "User",
  new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true }
  })
);
```

I'm seeing the JSON response in my browser with the information I'd expect, but I'm not seeing a new document in my database on MongoDB. What am I missing here? As far as I know when I call `.save()` on `newUser` the document should be showing up in MongoDB. In previous projects I did just this and it was working, and I can't figure out what's different in this situation.

And a broader question that I have that I didn't feel like was explained in the FCC curriculum is: at what point is a collection created in MongoDB by Mongoose? Is it when I create a new model? Like at this point in my code:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

exports.User = mongoose.model(
  "User",
  new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true }
  })
);
```

Or does it happen when I go to save an instance of the model? When is MongoDB told to create the collection? Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've done it again, the answer was very simple. I saw that I was getting an error from the `mongoose.connect()` call, because it was having trouble with the URI starting with `mongodb+srv://` instead of just `mongodb://`. I then saw that because I had forked the start project from FCC, it had some dated versions of Mongoose and MongoDB, just updating those two to the most recent versions (3.5.7 of MongoDB and 5.9.12 of Mongoose) solved the problem, and I'm now able to save the documents correctly!